# Lighthtpd ldap groupmember ignored

Tags: ldap, lighttpd

I have lighttpd 1.4.51 running a cgi app (git-http-backend) with ldap auth. This is working fine however when introducing the groupmember config item I cannot restrict logins to the specified group, so any user with a valid username and password is allowed.

lighttpd.conf:

```
auth.require = ( "" => (
        "method" => "basic",
        "realm" => "repos",
        "require" => "valid-user"
))
auth.backend = "ldap"
auth.backend.ldap.hostname              = "172.xx.xx.xx"
auth.backend.ldap.base-dn               = "OU=Current,OU=Company_Usrs,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk"
auth.backend.ldap.filter                = "(CN=$)"
auth.backend.ldap.bind-dn               = "CN=SVC_LDAP,OU=ServAccs,OU=ITS Admin,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk"
auth.backend.ldap.bind-pw               = "xxxx"
auth.backend.ldap.allow-empty-pw        = "disable"
auth.backend.ldap.groupmember           = "App_IT_Sol"
#auth.backend.ldap.groupmember          = "CN=App_IT_Sol,OU=Apps,OU=Grps,OU=Company_Res,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk"
#auth.backend.ldap.groupmember          = (memberUid=App_IT_Solution)
#auth.backend.ldap.groupmember          = "(member=CN=App_IT_Sol,OU=Apps,OU=Grps,OU=Company_Res,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk)"
```

After looking at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1817 I tried specifying the memberUid in the groupmember field along with a couple of other combinations, however there was no change.

The access, error and breakage logs do not show anything relevant.

Any ideas?

Solution:

```
auth.require = ( "" => (
        "method" => "basic",
        "realm" => "repos",
        "require" => "group=CN=App_IT_Sol,OU=Apps,OU=Grps,OU=Company_Res,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk"
))
auth.backend = "ldap"
auth.backend.ldap.hostname              = "172.xx.xx.xx"
auth.backend.ldap.base-dn               = "OU=Current,OU=Company_Usrs,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk"
auth.backend.ldap.filter                = "(CN=$)"
auth.backend.ldap.bind-dn               = "CN=SVC_LDAP,OU=ServAccs,OU=ITS Admin,DC=Company,DC=co,DC=uk"
auth.backend.ldap.bind-pw               = "xxxx"
auth.backend.ldap.allow-empty-pw        = "disable"
auth.backend.ldap.groupmember           = "member"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any user with a valid username and password is allowed

That is expected behavior with `"require" => "valid-user"`

Please try: `"require" => "group=App_IT_Sol"`

Comment: I needed to use the group DN in the require field, then 'member' in the groupmember field. Thanks for your help.